# JDO bidirectional one to many relationship add object

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus, google-cloud-sql

I have a class Autor and a class Dokument which are in a bidirectional 1 to n list relationship (1 Autor can have written several documents) which I want to persist into Cloud SQL. The orm is specified in package.jdo and package-cloudsql.orm.

Dokument class:

```
public class Autor {

    private String aid;

    private String vorname;

    private String nachname;

    private List<Dokument> dokumente;

    public Autor() {

    }

    public Autor(String vorname, String nachname) {
        this.vorname = vorname;
        this.nachname = nachname;
        this.dokumente = new ArrayList<Dokument>();
    }

    public String getAID() {
        return aid;
    }

    public String getVorname() {
        return vorname;
    }

    public String getNachname() {
        return nachname;
    }

    public List<Dokument> getDokumente() {
        return this.dokumente;
    }

    public void setAID(String aid) {
        this.aid = aid;
    }

    public void setVorname(String vorname) {
        this.vorname = vorname;
    }

    public void setNachname(String nachname) {
        this.nachname = nachname;
    }

    public void addDokument(Dokument dokument) {
        this.dokumente.add(dokument);
    }

    public void deleteDokument(Dokument dokument) {
        this.dokumente.remove(dokument);
    }

    public void deleteAllDokumente() {
        this.dokumente.clear();
    }

}
```

Dokument class:

```
public class Dokument {

    private String did;

    private Autor autor;

    private String titel;

    private String text;

    private Date datum;

    public Dokument() {

    }

    public Dokument(Autor autor, String titel, String text, Date datum) {
        this.autor = autor;
        this.titel = titel;
        this.text = text;
        this.datum = datum;
    }

    public Dokument(String titel, String text, Date datum) {
        this.autor = null;
        this.titel = titel;
        this.text = text;
        this.datum = datum;
    }

    public String getDid() {
        return did;
    }

    public Autor getAutor() {
        return autor;
    }

    public String getTitel() {
        return titel;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public Date getDatum() {
        return datum;
    }

    public void setDID(String did) {
        this.did = did;
    }

    public void setAutor(Autor autor) {
        this.autor = autor;
    }

    public void setTitel(String titel) {
        this.titel = titel;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public void setDatum(Date date) {
        this.datum = date;
    }
}
```

package.jdo contains this:

```
<class name="Autor" detachable="true" identity-type="application">
            <field name="aid" primary-key="true" persistence-modifier="persistent" value-strategy="identity"/>
            <field name="vorname"/>
            <field name="nachname" />
            <field name="dokumente"/>       
        </class>
        <class name="Dokument" detachable="true" identity-type="application">
            <field name="did" primary-key="true" persistence-modifier="persistent" value-strategy="identity"/>
            <field name="autor"/>
            <field name="titel"/>
            <field name="text"/>
            <field name="datum"/>
        </class>
```

package-sql.orm contains this:

```
<class name="Autor" detachable="true" persistence-modifier="persistence-capable" table="Autor">
            <field name="aid" primary-key="true" persistence-modifier="persistent" value-strategy="identity">
                <column name="aid" jdbc-type="bigint" length="20"/>
            </field>
            <field name="vorname" persistence-modifier="persistent">
                <column name="vorname"/>
            </field>    
            <field name="nachname" persistence-modifier="persistent">
                <column name="nachname"/>
            </field>
            <field name="dokumente" persistence-modifier="persistent" mapped-by="autor">
                <collection element-type="de.hdm.studienarbeit3.dokumente.Dokument"/>
            </field>
        </class>
        <class name="Dokument" detachable="true" persistence-modifier="persistence-capable" table="Dokument">
            <field name="did" primary-key="true" persistence-modifier="persistent" value-strategy="identity">
                <column name="did" jdbc-type="bigint" length="20" />
            </field>
            <field name="autor" persistence-modifier="persistent" default-fetch-group="true">
                <column name="autor" jdbc-type="bigint" length="20"/>
                <foreign-key name="DOKUMENTAUTOR_FK" delete-action="restrict"/>
            </field>
            <field name="titel" persistence-modifier="persistent">
                <column name="titel"/>
            </field>
            <field name="text" persistence-modifier="persistent">
                <column name="text"/>
            </field>
            <field name="datum" persistence-modifier="persistent">
                <column name="datum"/>
            </field>
        </class>
```

So I want to add a second (third and so on) Dokument to an existing Autor. But everytime I persist a Dokument it also creates a new Autor with attributes of the Autor i chose.
For example I have Autor with id 1 name "Hans Maier" and want to create another Dokument with him as Autor but the new dokument will have an Autor with id 2 and also the name "Hans Maier" what is not desired. I want the new dokument also be connected to Autor 1 then.

I have this code in my servlet:

```
if (autoraid=="") {
  if (vorname == "" | nachname =="") {
    resp.getWriter().println("Bitte Autor auswählen oder Namen vollständig ausfüllen.");
  } else {
     Autor autor = new Autor(vorname, nachname);
     Dokument dokument = new Dokument(autor, titel, text, datum);
     autor.addDokument(dokument);
     DokumentDAO dokumentDao = new DokumentDAO(pmf);
     dokumentDao.addDokument(autor, dokument);
 }
} else {
    AutorDAO autorDao = new AutorDAO(pmf);
    Autor autor = autorDao.getAutor(autoraid);
    Dokument dokument = new Dokument(autor, titel, text, datum);
    autor.addDokument(dokument);
    DokumentDAO dokumentDao = new DokumentDAO(pmf);
    dokumentDao.addDokument(autor, dokument);
}
```

autorDao.getAutor returns the autor which it has gotten by key (this works) and dokumentDao.addDokument() persists the given dokument with pm.makePersistent(dokument)

What am I missing or doing wrong? 
Datanucleus Documentation says I must set both ends when using List on bidirectional relationship http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jdo/orm/relationships.html what I am doing with setting Autor on Dokument creator and autor.addDokument(), but it doesn't work.

If I read dokument.getAutor().getAID() before persisting it returns the correct ID of the Autor I want it to be connected to but in database it is a new Autor. How can I make it work right?

I have read this http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/chap_07/index2.html and createBook method is exactly what i want to do, so I have also tested doing

```
public void addDokument(Autor autor, Dokument dokument) {

    PersistenceManager pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();
    Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();

    try {

      tx.begin();
        dokument.setAutor(autor);
        autor.addDokument(dokument);            
        pm.makePersistent(dokument);

       tx.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());

    } finally {
      if (tx.isActive()) {
        tx.rollback();
      }
      pm.close();
    }
    }
```

in the transaction, but same result, a new Autor is created.

any help will be appreciated.

The log says following:

```
Feb 18, 2014 1:23:33 PM org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.MappedTypeManager addMappedType
Schwerwiegend: User-defined type mapping class "org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.LocalDateMapping" was not found. Please check the mapping file class specifications and your CLASSPATH. The class must be in the CLASSPATH.
Feb 18, 2014 1:23:33 PM org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.MappedTypeManager addMappedType
Schwerwiegend: User-defined type mapping class "org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.LocalDateTimeMapping" was not found. Please check the mapping file class specifications and your CLASSPATH. The class must be in the CLASSPATH.
Feb 18, 2014 1:23:33 PM org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.MappedTypeManager addMappedType
Schwerwiegend: User-defined type mapping class "org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.LocalTimeMapping" was not found. Please check the mapping file class specifications and your CLASSPATH. The class must be in the CLASSPATH.
Feb 18, 2014 1:23:39 PM org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ForwardQueryResult closingConnection
Information: Reading in results for query "SELECT FROM de.hdm.studienarbeit3.dokumente.Autor ORDER BY nachname asc" since the connection used is closing
Feb 18, 2014 1:23:52 PM org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.MappedTypeManager addMappedType
Schwerwiegend: User-defined type mapping class "org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.LocalDateMapping" was not found. Please check the mapping file class specifications and your CLASSPATH. The class must be in the CLASSPATH.
Feb 18, 2014 1:23:52 PM org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.MappedTypeManager addMappedType
Schwerwiegend: User-defined type mapping class "org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.LocalDateTimeMapping" was not found. Please check the mapping file class specifications and your CLASSPATH. The class must be in the CLASSPATH.
Feb 18, 2014 1:23:52 PM org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.MappedTypeManager addMappedType
Schwerwiegend: User-defined type mapping class "org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.LocalTimeMapping" was not found. Please check the mapping file class specifications and your CLASSPATH. The class must be in the CLASSPATH.
```

org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.* used to be in datanucleus-core (at least in version 3.1.3.) but now in version 3.2.9. it isn't there anymore? where did it go? datanucleus-rdbms is also version 3.2.9.

The output of System.getProperty("java.class.path")

```
[workspace]\studienarbeit3\war\WEB-INF\classes
[workspace]\studienarbeit3\war\WEB-INF\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.28-bin.jar
[eclipse]\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.9\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.9\lib\shared\appengine-local-runtime-shared.jar
[eclipse]\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.9\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.9\lib\shared\el-api.jar
[eclipse]\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.9\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.9\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-ant-1.7.1.jar
[eclipse]\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.9\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.9\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-ant-launcher-1.7.1.jar
[eclipse]\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.9\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.9\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-jasper-6.0.29.jar
[eclipse]\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.9\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.9\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-jasper-el-6.0.29.jar
[eclipse]\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.9\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.9\lib\shared\jsp\repackaged-appengine-tomcat-juli-6.0.29.jar
[eclipse]\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.9\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.9\lib\shared\jsp-api.jar
[eclipse]\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.9\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.9\lib\shared\servlet-api.jar
[eclipse]\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.9\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.9\lib\appengine-tools-api.jar
[eclipse]\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.9\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.9\lib\opt\user\appengine-api-labs\v1\appengine-api-labs.jar
[eclipse]\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.9\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.9\lib\opt\user\appengine-endpoints\v1\appengine-endpoints-deps.jar
[eclipse]\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.9\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.9\lib\opt\user\appengine-endpoints\v1\appengine-endpoints.jar
[eclipse]\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.9\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.9\lib\opt\user\jsr107\v1\appengine-jsr107cache-1.8.9.jar
[eclipse]\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.9\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.9\lib\opt\user\jsr107\v1\jsr107cache-1.1.jar
[eclipse]\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.9\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.9\lib\user\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.8.9.jar
[eclipse]\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.9\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.9\lib\opt\user\datanucleus\v3\asm-4.0.jar
[eclipse]\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.9\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.9\lib\opt\user\datanucleus\v3\datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.8.jar
[eclipse]\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.9\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.9\lib\opt\user\datanucleus\v3\datanucleus-appengine-3.0.0.jar
[eclipse]\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.9\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.9\lib\opt\user\datanucleus\v3\datanucleus-core-3.2.9.jar
[eclipse]\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.9\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.9\lib\opt\user\datanucleus\v3\datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar
[eclipse]\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.9\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.9\lib\opt\user\datanucleus\v3\jdo-api-3.1-rc1.jar
[eclipse]\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.9\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.9\lib\opt\user\datanucleus\v3\jta-1.1.jar
[workspace]\studienarbeit3\war\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar
[workspace]\studienarbeit3\war\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar
[eclipse]\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.9\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.9\lib\impl\google_sql.jar
[eclipse]\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.9\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.9\lib\agent\appengine-agent.jar
```

Comment: "it doesn't work". So why not be precise ? what does the log say? It tells you about object lifecycle etc, the state objects are in when being persisted, and you don't provide classes or exact persistence code so guesswork is all that people are left with. The log is for just that situation (and please don't come back and say "there's nothing in the log", because it will be a large file when DEBUG level is used).

Comment: I would like to provide you the log, but I have no idea where it is. Can you tell me where I can find it? I have copied the java.util.logging example from here http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/logging.html but can't find any output

Comment: I have added now classes and the code of DokumentDao.addDokument(Autor autor, Dokument dokument)

Comment: The log is where you configure it to be ... your log configuration defines the filename. This is java.util.logging standard, so a useful thing to know about independent of DataNucleus

Comment: Ok I have found the file, I should have read the comments they provided better, but which levels do I have to set to get useful output? I have it on all now, and the persisting does not create any log entry, just retreiving data creates one log entry and there are thee fatal exceptions because of some date/timemapping, i will insert it into my post so you can see it

Comment: If there is a reference to some class for its 3.1 location then you have a 3.1 datanucleus jar in your CLASSPATH ...

Comment: I have discovered org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.* is now in datanucleus-appengine-plugin 3.0 jar which i actually have in my build path, why is it not found and how can i make it available to the project?

Comment: Decide if you're persisting to Google CLoud SQL, or GAE/Datastore. If using Google Cloud SQL then delete that "datanucleus-appengine" jar.

Comment: The application should be able to connect to both to be able to compare them, that's my problem.
when using appengine-datanucleus-plugin 2.1.2. and datanucleus 3.1.3. I had problem with primary key since datastore requires encoded string or key and string to bigint mapper was faulty in this version as you can see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588107/datanucleus-jdo-map-string-to-mysql-type-bigint-in-app-engine apart from that it worked with both (when I changed type of primary key to string or long), so i don't know why it doesn't work with new plugin version

Answer (score 0):

As [Google's compatibility doc](https://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/wiki/Compatibility) says their GAE/Datastore plugin (datanucleus-appengine) is only compatible with DataNucleus 3.1. There is a [build](http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2/com/google/appengine/orm/datanucleus-appengine/) of SVN of their plugin (that works with DataNucleus 3.2/3.3) in the DataNucleus Maven repo (but ask Google why they are too lazy to release this, it's been in their SVN for a year or more). Your other thread says you need DataNucleus 3.2+ for use with Google Cloud SQL. In conclusion, it's totally obvious why you can't mix and match DataNucleus jar versions; pick the version you're using and get appropriate jars.

Comment: actually i am using this Datanucleus-AppEngine-Plugin-3.0. from the Datanucleus website in my buildpath.

Comment: So look in the log, because only you see what versions of all of these jars are actually in the CLASSPATH.

Comment: I have added a list of the jars which are in WEB-INF/lib, I don't see any missing or outdated versions there (there is no datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.9.jar in maven repositories yet, accessplatform 3.3.7 also ships with this version and core and rdbms in version 3.2.9.)

Comment: that's only part of the CLASSPATH. System.getProperty("java.class.path") would likely show more. Your message claims that some mapped.mapping class is not found, yet it's obviously in datanucleus-appengine-3.0.0.jar (as you could easily check). If it can't find that then that jar is hidden (by something else ...)

Comment: ok i have replaced it by output of System.getProperty("java.class.path"). Datanucleus is listed too, what could it be hidden by?

Comment: ok I have found out that both plugin.xml - of datanucleus-rdbms and datanucleus-appengine specify their mapping classes and in Dokument I have a field of type Date, is it possible that both plugins conflict each other? Since I don't see why rdbms should call an appengine class, the mapping class sepcified in rdms plugin.xml is "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.java.LocalDateMapping". So I guess it can't find it because it hasn't imported it as this class is not supposed to be used there.

Comment: No idea about GAE's own plugin using what is basically an RDBMS extension point; it was a bad design decision by GAE and certainly won't help the situation. But suggest you can easily check whether that is the problem by removing the aforementioned datanucleus-appengine jar from your CLASSPATH. If it isn't that then get back to your real problem.

Comment: Ok I have found my fault. I did not think of detaching the Autor object when I got it from database so it was in hollow state, that's why jdo created a new Autor object in database.